# Redirect in javascript function, coeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I have the following function that will show a pop up message, once the user click ok it will navigate the user to the controller called backendBanner and call the function delete_banner.

The link written in html and php looks something like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url().'backendBanner/delete_banner/'.$banner['banner_path']; ?>">
```

Code for the button in view to call the function

```
<td>
      <a onclick="return remove_image($(this));" rel="<?php echo $banner['banner_path']; ?>"><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete"></a>
</td>
```

Code for the function
In this function, $banner['banner_path'] is equal to fullpath

```
<script>
        function remove_image(img)
        {
            if(confirm('<?php echo lang('confirm_remove_image');?>'))
            {
                var fullpath  = img.attr('rel');
                alert(fullpath);
                redirect(base_url()."backendBanner/delete_banner/"+fullpath);
            }
        }
    </script>
```

How should I go about bringing the user to the link through the function?

Comment: how are you currently calling the `remove_image()` function?

Comment: It should be `window.location="<?php echo base_url().'backendBanner/delete_banner/'.$banner['banner_path']; ?>" + fullpath`

Comment: Always use a console when you're working with clientside code, it will tell you if you're using an undefined function.

Comment: you are vulnerable to JS injection attacks. don't echo out arbitrary text from PHP into a JS context. if your translation of `confirm_remove_image` contains **ANY** quote characters you'll be introducing a JS syntax error and killing the entire `<script>` block. always output text into JS via `json_encode()`.

Comment: @VickyGonsalves Thanks for your help. It works well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting passed value in controller from view, codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34950269/getting-passed-value-in-controller-from-view-codeigniter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be :

```
window.location="<?php echo base_url().'backendBanner/delete_banner/'.$banner['banner_path']; ?>" + fullpath
```

Comment: Can u also help me with another problem that I am facing? The value of fullpath is dynamic it can be in the following format "assets/images/banner3.jpg" and "banner4.jpg".

The problem I am facing is that, when the fullpath is "assets/images/banner3.jpg" and I var_dump the value of $image_name in the delete_banner controller, it only returns "assets" instead of "assets/images/banner3.jpg".

Comment: try `var_dump($banner)` and check ?

Comment: the value is pass over through "fullpath"

Comment: Can you create  php fiddle?

Comment: When i var_dump(fullpath) it is  "assets/images/banner3.jpg"

Comment: Then u might need to change to `window.location="<?php echo base_url().'backendBanner/delete_banner/'.$banner['fullpath']; ?>"
`

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your JS code is that you're using `redirect()`. This will not work because `redirect()` is a PHP/Codeigniter function, not JS.

Use `window.location` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the function **base_url()** it's a valid function created by you...

Try with:

```
location.href = base_url() + img.attr('rel');
```

Note: Try to use some templating engine like twig, blade etc.